# C++ Lost UDP packets that in real they are delayed

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, pthreads

I have a UDP connection that connects an echo server with a test client. test client continuously sends packets and waits about a second for receiving them.
if it can't get the packet, assumes that packet is lost and sends another packet. 
Most of the packets are sent and received successfully but some of them that assumed to be lost, will be receive in client after sending next packet. actually they are received with delay.
my send and receive function run on different thread.
what can I do for eliminating these delayed packets?
(my program is running on my localhost- so having lost packets is not reasonable)

Comment: Choice only one language, UDP is UDP if you need more feature look for another protocol as TCP.

Comment: Sequence numbers. If you receive a reply-packet with a sequence number lower than the last you sent out, then just ignore it.

Comment: If you are dealing with UDP you should be ready for packets getting lost, reordered and duplicated. "my send and receive function run on different thread" remark makes me think that this is actually a multithreading issue in your application, not packets getting lost (which is indeed unlikely to happen on localhost).

Comment: it seems that packet with lower sequence number arrives sooner,  @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: What do you mean by that? Lets say that you send out packet #1 and get a reply. Then you send out packet #2, but the reply is delayed. So you continue by sending out packet #3, but before you get its reply you get the reply for #2. Then just ignore #2, and continue waiting for #3. And so on. If you receive #2 before you send #3, then all is well.

Comment: I am sure that my packet from client is sent and also sure that in echo server I am in socket receive timeout  how can I be sure that it is not a threading problem @VTT

Comment: Check how code accesses shared variables, run it under some verification tool, such as Cuzz.

Comment: this is the thing that happened to me( you send out packet #1 and get a reply. Then you send out packet #2, but the reply is delayed. So you continue by sending out packet #3, but before you get its reply you get the reply for #2. Then just ignore #2, and continue waiting for #3) an get reply for #3. but it is not reasonable to get a packet after sending next pkt it should be lost @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Receiving packet #2 while waiting for packet #3 is kind of what ***I*** mean by "delay". The packet #2 have been *delayed* somewhere along the route.

Comment: if I wait for long time ,without sending next packet, that delayed packet can't get @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Thanks All, my problem solved. Delay of select in receive should be smaller that time of waiting for receiving packet in main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks All.

Delay of select in receive should be smaller that time of waiting for receiving thread packet in main

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you will not be able to prevent package delays (maybe due to buffers in the network interface, kernel, application stack). UDP is unreliable, if you need to make sure that every package is delivered you should use TCP in general. Otherwise there would be options like using sequence numbers or a more elaborate protocol implmenetation to make sure that you are not out of sequence (like a confirmation for each package).

What you describe sounds more like using TCP would be appropriate though.

Answer (score -1):

It can happen if there is network congestion or proxy/firewall enabled.
Check the network signal strength.
Remove if any firewall settings are enabled in your local network.
Switch to some best channel with good strength in your router.

Comment: `my program is running on my localhost` not likely to be a proxy or firewall issue.  Worse, trying to fix the wireless channel would at best just hide the  problem rather than resolve it.

Comment: As UDP is unreliable, packet drop is most common issue. So, you can do couple of things, in order to make sure all packets are getting received, after sending a packet wait for an acknowledgement from client and then send the next packet. If client is not acknowledging in certain interval re-transmit the same packet again. This way at least it will ensure all packets delivered successfully but it will slow down the performance.          second way don't send data frequently rather put it in buffer and transmit buffer.

Comment: `As UDP is unreliable, packet drop is most common issue.` not when used on the local machine it's not.  Even if it is, if the application can't deal with packet loss, that's the thing to fix; not trying to improve packet loss %.

Comment: `If client is not acknowledging in certain interval re-transmit the same packet again.` That's called TCP.